# What is the meaning of an asterisk appended to a TFS changeset number

Tags: version-control, tfs, changeset

I am looking at candidate changesets for a merge and I get some output I don't understand:

```
tf merge /candidate /recursive $/Acme/Branches/Release/3.5 $/Acme/Trunk
Changeset Author                           Date
--------- -------------------------------- ----------
   47829* nate:14                          4/16/2009
```

What does the * at the end of the changeset number mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It indicates a partial merge was done.

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate on Randy's answer: a partial merge means that some of the changes in #47829 have already been merged but others have not.

**tf merges** uses the same syntax.  Starting in 2008 (or maybe it was 2005 SP1?) there's also a **/format:detailed** parameter that will enumerate the merge history item-by-item.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it means those changesets have already been merged from the source branch to the target branch locally, but the changes have not been checked in on the target branch yet. If you check in pending changes on the target branch and then run "tf /merge /candidate ..." you shouldn't have any items with an asterisk.